# Top and Left menu

Tags: angular, spring, spring-boot

I am new in angular application with **Spring Boot**. I wanted to create sample app with **Top** and **Left** menu.
Menu will dynamically populate from database. Assume I have **TopMenuTable** and **LeftMenuTable**.

**TopMenuTable** has three entries:

- Books
- Computer/Pad
- Gift

**LeftMenuTable** has entries as follwoing:

- Comic, Jokes, Thriller => for **Books** child entries
- Desktop, Laptop, Mouse Pad => for **Computer/Pad** child entries
- Flower Vase, Coffee Mug => for **Gifts** child entries.

How can I accomplish **TopMenuTable** items are in **Top** menu, and **LeftMenuTable** items are in **Left** side menu?

Wanted to have an example with **Angular** and **SpringBoot**. 
Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

What about this suggestion:

- you create a table for MenuEntry:

  ```
  create table MENU_ENTRY
  (
      ID  NUMBER constraint MENU_ENTRY_PK primary key,
      TITLE   VARCHAR2(200) not null,
      MENU_PARENT_ID NUMBER, -- parent here is ID of either: Books, Computer or Gift
      MENU_TYPE_ID  NUMBER constraint FK_MENU_TYPE references MENU_TYPE(ID)
  )
  ```
- you create a table for menu type ( suppose you don't have only 2 types of menu)

```
    create table MENU_TYPE
        (
            ID      NUMBER  constraint MENU_TYPE_PK primary key,
            TITLE VARCHAR2(20) -- either TOP, LEFT or maybe RIGHT
        )
```

Comment: Thank you Dev. Could you please share code/sample project using these two tables.